# MSP430 8 vs 16 bit memory/bus?

Tags: msp430

I want to make sure im understanding something correctly. Im learning the MSP430G2 (specifically G2553 is the actual chip im using).

Im def. a newb to computer architecture so keep that in mind.

So from the datasheet/books im reading, the data/address bus is 16 bits wide (2 bytes). And a Word size is 16 bits (2 bytes) (although im still not sure what word means in this context).

However the memory addresses are only 8 bits in size (1 byte). So everytime we send a word? or Opcode, are we storing it in 2 memory addresses? (I read that the MSP430 only looks at the lowest significant BYTE and that it has to be even)

So if were storing a word or instruction (Im not sure if they mean the same thing in this context). Were storing the LSB in the lower memory location (like 0x0200) and the MSB(byte) in 0x0201 for example. But the CPU is only actually reading the LSB? Is this correct?

Comment: This question is too indistinct at present to be answerable.  Generally speaking, an instruction set provides fully unique addressing of memory operations, though some instruction formats may only support a limited displacement from a base address, rather than the full range.  If a pointer or instruction word of width greater than the memory width must be stored, it is stored in successive addresses least significant byte first or most significant byte first depending on the architecture.

Comment: In contrast, hardware address decoding may be incomplete, in that specific physical memory regions may alias several times within the address space.

Comment: The question and problem at hand are perfectly clear and understandable! It being a simple beginner question does not make it "unclear"

Comment: I don't understand why this question is being downvoted. Im asking about a specific MCU and a specific question about the widths of memory and instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So from the datasheet/books im reading, the data/address bus is 16 bits wide (2 bytes). And a Word size is 16 bits (2 bytes) (although im still not sure what word means in this context).

An `address` is conceptually a **pointer** to a location in memory, this location in memory is usually defined to hold one architecture `word`.

For most purposes the the `word size` represents smallest *addressable unit* . And the `address size` dictates the maximum number of addressable units. Address size also can be defined as the size of the register holding a pointer to address some memory.

#### Instruction vs Data:

On many modern CPU's there is a seperate and distinct `instruction bus` and `data bus` with their own `instruction bus width` and `data bus width` (instruction and data `word size`) as well as `instruction address width` and `data address width`. Additional memory buses may exist as well (with their own addressing schema)

For convenience these sizes may be chosen to coincide so that mixing data and instructions ([Modified Harvard Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Harvard_architecture) ) in the same physical memory hardware is simplified. In the case of the MSP430 series, they use a von Neumann architecture where words and instructions are loaded and executed from the same address space.

> However the memory addresses are only 8 bits in size (1 byte). So everytime we send a word? or Opcode, are we storing it in 2 memory addresses? (I read that the MSP430 only looks at the lowest significant BYTE and that it has to be even)

In this cpu, the `word size` is in fact **16 bits**. However, there are multiple addressing modes available depending on opcode, in most addressing modes the address points to a `word` of memory or an offset. Certain instructions may allow subaddressing into the word (and you can implicitly extend the `address width` of the architecture in this mode), often for optimization purposes (instruction packing and vectored instructions).

**Physical Memory Geometry**

The layout of physical memory may not necessarily match the architecture width. So the transaction between the physical memory and the instruction cache of the CPU may happen in a variety of ways and it is not necessarily important if it loads a word at a time or not.

> So if were storing a word or instruction (Im not sure if they mean the same thing in this context). Were storing the LSB in the lower memory location (like 0x0200) and the MSB(byte) in 0x0201 for example. But the CPU is only actually reading the LSB? Is this correct?

Conceptually the instruction occupies one `word` of memory and is read from instruction memory in a single piece, the instruction occupies a single address `0x0200` points to a 16 bit `word`, due to byte addressing the next word begins address 0x2002, if you simply mask the last bit this is a 15 bit address that increments by one. The extra byte index bit is masked for all word address  operations.

It is also possible that the physical SDRAM or Flash Memory is organized by single bytes or even several hundred bytes and that the ram controller (a hardware device) translates the architecture address to an address that makes sense for the physical memory, but this is an implementation detail and not an architecture detail and does not dictate the Address and Data Width

**Memory addressing in opcodes**

Some instructions will require you to reference a an address in memory as part of the instruction (add, etc). If you have 16 bit addresses and 16 bit instructions, then there is now way to both store operation information and an entire address in a single op-code/instruction.

In this case a masking or offset scheme is used.

It is very common that the interacting with instruction addresses (branch and jumps) are defined as offsets to the given instruction pointer or masking it with the . This allows you to store an offset as 4/8/12 bits and lets you use 16 bit opcodes with memory inside the opcode.

An alternative is an op-code that uses a register or an address of data memory storing a full memory address.

In this case the CPU architecture is designed to operate on byte or word addressed modes.

Comment: Im a little bit confused, you are saying each memory address points to a word of memory (a word being 16 bits). However im reading the MSP430 book and it's denoting that a word is actually 2 memory addresses. http://imgur.com/Jj475RQ  (see image for what im saying)

Comment: @msmith1114 This CPU provides byte or word addressing somewhat of a convenient architecture choice. In this case each hardware address points to a specific byte, a byte address can be easily constructed from a word address by appending a `0` LSB to a word address. This is a Von Neumman Architecture device so no distinction is made for Data vs Instructions. In Harvard archicture devices it is rarer for byte addressing to be used for instructions (since operations are always word aligned but data is not)

Comment: The MSP430 naturally uses 16 bit words, but can do 8 bit access without issue. You can read or write in 8 bits if you want.

Comment: @Passerby correct, that is a much more concise way to put it, I would call it a mixed architecture strictly, but it is seen often.

Comment: Why wouldn't you describe word side as the register size? It seems misleading (particularly in the context of theis question) to take address resolution as your reference, then say actually it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

On the MSP430, a word has 16 bits. Why? Because TI defined it this way.

Memory addresses have a size of one word (16 bits, 2 bytes).

The CPU has a 16-bit data bus; when reading a word, it reads both bytes at once.

Answer (score 1):

"Word" is the amount of bytes the CPU is capable of processing at once. In other words, MSP430's ALU is 16 bit width and it can process two 16 bit "words" at once.

The program counter (PC) register is 16 bit, but the LSB (Less Significant Bit) of PC is always read as 0; hence it can only access even memory addresses, and the memory has to be aligned (Memory alignment will make more sense after reading the next paragraphs). On a side note, each assembler line can use more than 1 word of memory, depending on where the source and destiny are located.

Memory addresses are 16 bit as well, but each individual address can only hold 1 byte (8 bits), so in order to store a single instruction two memory cells must be read at once.

Every even memory address can be accessed as word; this means that 0x200, 0x202, 0x204, and so on can be read as "word".
However, this is not true for odd memory addresses. These can only be accessed as byte. Even memory addresses can also be accessed as byte. So 0x200, 0x201 (byte only), 0x202, 0x203 (byte only), and so on.

How data is stored in memory is related with endianess. MSP430 is little endian, so the "end" (LSB) is stored in the "little" address. So if you store a 32 bit value in address 0x300, MSB will be in 0x303 and LSB will be in 0x300.

Some MSP430 have a CPUx instead a CPU "core", and they are able to address a 20 bit width address bus. However, MSP430G2553 does not have CPUx.